# I want to implement the on_touch_down function when a pick is pressed, but don't know how to implement it

Tags: python, kivy

I want when this image in my python file is pushed, I want to use the on_touch_down function instead the on_release function. if anyone could be of any assistance I would appreciate it.

```
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.profileimage = ImageButton(source= "icons/profilepic.png", pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.65})
        self.profileimage.bind(on_release= self.imagechange)
        self.add_widget(self.profileimage)
```

Thanks for future assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `on_press` instead of `on_release`.